# Set background depending on a value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, toast, dynamicresource

I need to set the background value depending on a value that you receive in the constructor.
The types are:

```
public enum EToastType
{
    Error,
    Info,
    Success,
    Warning
}
```

CustomMessage.xaml:

```
<core:NotificationDisplayPart x:Class="Presentacion.Notificaciones.CustomMessage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:ToastNotifications.Core;assembly=ToastNotifications"
mc:Ignorable="d"  Background="{**I NEED SET VALUE**}"
d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="250">
<Grid  Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

CustomMesage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CustomMessage : NotificationDisplayPart
{
    public CustomMessage(ToastDto toast)
    {
        DataContext = toast;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ToastDto.cs:

```
public class ToastDto
{
    public EToastType Color { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And App.xaml:

```
<Application 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <Color x:Key="InformationColor">#147ec9</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InformationColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource InformationColor}" options:Freeze="True" />

        <Color x:Key="SuccessColor">#11ad45</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SuccessColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource SuccessColor}" options:Freeze="True" />

        <Color x:Key="ErrorColor">#e60914</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ErrorColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" options:Freeze="True" />

        <Color x:Key="WarningColor">#f5a300</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WarningColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource WarningColor}" options:Freeze="True" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then depending on the EToastType value that is sent to the CustomMessage constructor, the background property in CustomMessage has to take a value of App.xaml

Comment: what is the question? You can use converter, isn't it?

Comment: I do not know how that is used, what I want is for the CustomMessage.xaml background to use one of the static resources of App.xaml depending on the value of EToastType

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom `IValueConverter` to convert your `EToastType` to `Brush`.

```
public class EToastTypeToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush Error { get; set; }
    public Brush Info { get; set; }
    public Brush Success { get; set; }
    public Brush Warning { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is EToastType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case EToastType.Error:
                    return Error;
                case EToastType.Info:
                    return Info;
                case EToastType.Success:
                    return Success;
                case EToastType.Warning:
                    return Warning;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

By using this converter, just initialize a new instance with each brush property in your resource dictionary.

```
<local:EToastTypeToBrushConverter x:Key="EToastTypeToBrushConverter"
    Info="{StaticResource InformationColorBrush}"
    Success="{StaticResource SuccessColorBrush}"
    Error="{StaticResource ErrorColorBrush}"
    Warning="{StaticResource WarningColorBrush}"/>
```

---

**EDIT**: If you want a more universal `IValueConverter`, you can write such code instead of `EToastTypeToBrushConverter`:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Conversions))]
public class EnumToObjectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Collection<EnumConversion> Conversions { get; } = new Collection<EnumConversion>();
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => Conversions.FirstOrDefault(x => Equals(x.Source, value))?.Target;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

But in this way, XAML usage will be more complex:

```
<local:EnumToObjectConverter x:Key="EToastTypeToBrushConverter">
    <local:EnumConversion Target="{StaticResource InformationColorBrush}">
        <local:EnumConversion.Source>
            <local:EToastType>Info</local:EToastType>
        </local:EnumConversion.Source>
    </local:EnumConversion>
    <local:EnumConversion Target="{StaticResource SuccessColorBrush}">
        <local:EnumConversion.Source>
            <local:EToastType>Success</local:EToastType>
        </local:EnumConversion.Source>
    </local:EnumConversion>
    <local:EnumConversion Target="{StaticResource ErrorColorBrush}">
        <local:EnumConversion.Source>
            <local:EToastType>Error</local:EToastType>
        </local:EnumConversion.Source>
    </local:EnumConversion>
    <local:EnumConversion Target="{StaticResource WarningColorBrush}">
        <local:EnumConversion.Source>
            <local:EToastType>Warning</local:EToastType>
        </local:EnumConversion.Source>
    </local:EnumConversion>
</local:EnumToObjectConverter>
```